# Solr Schema Design

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have some questions regarding the solr schema design. Basically I'm setting up a search engine for product catalogue website and my table relationships are as follows.

- `Product` Belongs to `Merchant`
- `Product` Belongs to `Brand`
- `Product` has and belongs to many `Categories`
- `Category` has many `Sub Categories`
- `Sub Category` has many `Types`
- `Type` has many `Sub Types`

So far my Schema.xml is looks like this.

```
<field name="product_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="merchant" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="merchant_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="brand" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="brand_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="categories" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="sub_categories" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="types" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="sub_types" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="price" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="image" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<uniqueKey>product_id</uniqueKey>

<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="merchant" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="brand" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="categories" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="sub_categories" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="types" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="sub_types" dest="text"/>
```

So my Questions now:

1) Is the Schema correct?

2) Let's assume I need to find products for `Category XYZ`. My Senior programer doesn't like querying the solr by `Category Name`, instead he wan't to use `CategoryID`. 
He is suggesting to store  `CategoryID_CategoryName (1001_Category XYZ)` and from web front he is sending ID. (Assuming that Names with white spaces doesn't work properly).

So to find the products I should then do a partial match of `categories` and identify the category id from the string i.e `(fetch 1001 from 1001_Category XYZ)`
or
What if I keep the Names on `categories` field and setup another field for `category_ids`? that's seems a better option for me.

or

is there any Solr multi valued field type to store `CategoryID` and `CategoryName` together?

Let me know your thoughts, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to your questions.

1. Maybe - it depends on how you plan on structuring your queries, what you intend to search and what you intend to retrieve in search results. In your schema, you're storing & indexing everything which can be quite inefficient. Index what you intend to query, store what you intend to retrieve/display. If you were looking for optimizations, I would review the datatypes used in the schema - try to stay as native to the source type as you can.
2. Querying by CategoryId - your programmer is correct, you want to query by category Id. Your approach of storing Ids and Names in separate fields is accurate as well. Presuming your Id-based fields are integers/longs, you don't want to structure them as strings but rather as integers/longs.

Comment: thank you very much for this. -- Yes I understand now, I shouldn't index/store all the fields. But we do have a plan, not to fetch any product data from database anymore, instead we are going to read all the product data from Solr. Because of that reason, we still need every field on Solr.